# Wordpress Gravity Forms API not returning up to date result

Tags: json, wordpress, gravityforms

I have Gravity Forms 2.5 installed on a WordPress site and I'm using the Gravity Forms V2 API to get the details of the form:

```
GET /wp-json/gf/v2/forms/2
```

However, the JSON that is returned doesn't include all of the values for one of the drop-down fields. The drop-down is populating the values from a Pods feed.

[image: Gravity Forms Drop-down Settings]

It shows up on the web form, but not in the API.

[image: Web form choices]

[image: API Results]

Do I need to do anything to get the API to return the latest values from the Pods?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, by going into the Gravity Form, clicking "Edit Choices" and then clicking "Save Form"

[image: Edit Gravity Form Choices]